# How to access Angular service in a view expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular documentation advises to use Angular services Angular expressions:

> Instead use services like $window and $location in functions called from expressions. Such services provide mockable access to globals.

– https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#context

However, these services do not appear to be in the view scope by default, e.g.

```
{{$location || 'Undefined'}}
```

Will produce "Undefined".

If I want to access `$location` service from a view, do I need to inject it to the scope?

```
/* some controller */ function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.$location = $location;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Expose methods and properties to views via $scope. Although bit of an anti-pattern because you are tightly coupling the view with $location. You should abstract to a method or better still, a directive.

Comment: This was more "out of curiosity" question than practical. The documentation is a bit misleading in this aspect. It implies that $window service is available in the expression context.

Comment: Not sure it is... but either way, to "adhere" to the testable patterns in Angular, you should probably use either a method call into the controller, or a directive, that encapsulates what you are trying to do. I'll attempt an answer..

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here is to encapsulate what you are trying to do within either a controller method call, or a directive. So for example, if you wanted to bring the current URL through to the view, you should probably do something like the following.

VIEW

```
<p>{{ CurrentUrl }}</p>
```

CONTROLLER

```
(function(app){

    app.controller("myController",["$scope","$location",function($scope,$location){

        $scope.CurrentUrl = $location.$$path; // or whatever is most useful to display

    }]);

})(myApp);
```

This means that you are following the IOC pattern of Angular, and not tightly coupling "$location" to either your view or your controller.

Using "$location" here is obviously just an example. You could use "$window" or whatever you wanted.

Comment: Gajus Kuizinas - I have rolled back your edit. Because it wasn't an edit it was your version of what the OP wanted - not mine. If you want to answer the question, do so.

Comment: Yes, and also prevents to expose $location var.